# Any analogue for Q.anySettled promise in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, q

Shortly about the task. We have an array of promises that could either resolve or reject. To understand whether total result is good or not - we need to know results of all promises in array.

In JQuery (our usual **go-to library** for promises) `$.when.apply()` works in a way that if one of the promises in array is rejected - main promise for the whole array is instantly rejected too, without waiting for all array element results, so this solution is not an option.

In Q library there's a `.allSetteled()` method that does the thing nicely. But I was wondering if there is some way to implement the same functionality using JQuery (because we're already using it in the project).

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: I didn't find any workable solution for such conditions in JQuery documentation. I've made sure that $.when.apply doesn't solve the problem (code used mostly from another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777031/what-does-when-apply-somearray-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is indeed similar to one mentioned in comment by Bergi:
"You're right, there is no such method in jQuery. See my answer to the possible duplicate question [$.Deferred: How to detect when every promise has been executed for a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177087/deferred-how-to-detect-when-every-promise-has-been-executed)". In the link you can also fine couple of possible workarounds.