# Multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

From and according to jQuery API, in the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when() immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at that point.

My issue I need the successful requests, and how can I filter or work with the success jqXHR, and group them as resolved, leaving out the failed request?

```
$.when( $.get(API string 1), $.get(API string 2) , $.get(API string 3) , $.get(API string 4) , $.get(API string 5) ...).then(function() {
    // Just want the successful jqXHR objects here and resolve them, so i can return promise object
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises

Comment: For any one looking to resolve this issue, found a link on here that worked and helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177087/deferred-how-to-detect-when-every-promise-has-been-executed